# WMS GetFeatureInfo for multiple overlapping layers at the same time (Geoserver)

Tags: geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have two layers served via GeoServer: "locations and "forests".

I'm using GetFeatureInfo request to query the layers like this:

`mysite.net/geoserver/project/wms?REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&SERVICE=WMS&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&STYLES=&TRANSPARENT=true&VERSION=1.1.1&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&BBOX=16.52648448944092%2C45.730599026324924%2C16.569614410400394%2C45.7570142556995&HEIGHT=882&WIDTH=1005&LAYERS=project%3Alocations%2project%3Aforests&QUERY_LAYERS=project%3Alocations%2Cproject%3Aforests&INFO_FORMAT=text%2Fhtml&X=383&Y=390`

This works fine, but in cases where layers overlap, I get only the response for first layer (locations), and I need featureInfo for both layers. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to add &FEATURE_COUNT=10

Comment: It worked, thanks. I suppose &FEATURE_COUNT=2 would suffice for two layers?

Comment: It's interesting that in the WMS 1.3.0 specification we have `The optional FEATURE_COUNT parameter states the maximum number of features per layer for which feature information shall be returned.` whilst in the WMS 1.1.1 specification it doesn't mention per layer

Comment: Geoserver is using a buffer when it processes the GetFeatureInfo request. The buffer can be set in request, or it may be a fixed value that is configured on the server side, or server sets is automatically with complex heuristics, which is the default https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/services/wms/vendor.html?highlight=getfeatureinfo#buffer. This means that GetFeatureInfo may find several hits from a layer and it may be safer to use a somewhat bigger value as FEATURE_COUNT.